# How to extract Json values from JDBC request from result array

Tags: jmeter

I have a jdbc request to get specific values from JSON which is stored in column.

**JDBC request:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

{"Status": "A", "UserId": "HUCQ02D5", "IsDiaryVisible": true, "ParticipantName": "Dr. Mary, Angelina [SP000001]"}

I need to store or validate above values like Status, UserId, etc.,

Debug Sampler shows following.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can point [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to read the source from a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

[image]

Just come up with an appropriate [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) query and that would be it.

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

Comment: I have added JSON extractor as shown above I see only Status=NOT_FOUND in debug sampler.